# Transport equation problem with boundary condition: $a(x,y)u_x + b(x,y)u_y = -u \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ \overline{\Omega}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit disk and $u \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ solution of
$$a(x,y)u_x + b(x,y)u_y = -u \ \ \mbox{in} \ \ \overline{\Omega}.$$
If $a(x,y)x + b(x,y)y > 0$, for all $x,y \in \partial \Omega$, show that $u \equiv 0$.

**Hint:** Show that $\displaystyle\max_{\Omega} u \leq 0$ and $\displaystyle\min_{\Omega} u \geq 0$.

Comment: What have you tried? What techniques do you have at your disposal?

Comment: I tried using characteristic equations to solve. I separated it into two cases, when the maximum is reached inside $\Omega$ and at the border of $\Omega$. I was blocked in the second situation...